# Check Format for Json in Lua

Tags: json, lua

How can one check to see if a string is properly formatted in json? I am running into situations where I receive a partial json string, and then when trying to decode the erroneous string with Lua's json.decode, my application crashes.

Thanks

Comment: Lua doesn't have a standard JSON decoder. Which one are you using? If you could also provide the exact code that you invoke, that would also help.

Comment: Well, it looks like http://json.luaforge.net/ is used. Next step - can you provide version of library you used and string caused crash?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a difference between crash and crash in Lua.

If you see segfaults, throw away your JSON library and use something else (there are [plenty](http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules)).

If you see a Lua error, just wrap JSON processing code in `pcall` or `xpcall`. (But, better, again, throw away your library, and pick a better one).